# Android :NDK: Library function :newStringUTF("My Library"); not changing the string in output

Tags: c++, android-ndk

when i try to change words onto the Native code file(ndktest.c) 
here "return (*env).NewStringUTF("My Library");"
"My Library " to "My" then in the output it keeps on showing me "My Library" rather than "My" how can i fix this....Can you help me Thanks!

1-this is the java side code.

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");
    }
    public native String HelloJNI();
```

2-this is the c/c++ side code.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_happy_ndktest_MyNDK_HelloJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    return (*env).NewStringUTF("My");
```

Comment: Show your code please.  Otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: In addition to showing us the code you should also verify that you've saved the code changes, rebuilt the code and the APK, and installed the new version of the APK.

Comment: Thanks! all of you whom commented, @Michael I've done all of it saved changes,rebuilt and then installed. but still getting error. I'm showing you pics now.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks! here is the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
When you debug your code and show output in emulator or running device, make sure you built each time ndk libraries.